# Error with urlgrabber

Tags: python

The following code for retreiving an image from url fails.
For some reason, it throws a KeyboardInterrupt (???) which throws my script even if I surround it with try-catch....

Question is, why does it fail, when the url exists?

```
>>> import urlgrabber
>>> urlgrabber.urlgrab('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/Passion_Flower.JPG/220px-Passion_Flower.JPG', filename='/home/eran/a.tmp', timeout = 2, retry = 2, reget = 'simple')
```

This creates the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1098, in _hdr_retrieve
    self.size = int(length)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Age, Content-Length, Date, X-Cache, X-Varnish\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1098, in _hdr_retrieve
    self.size = int(length)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Age, Content-Length, Date, X-Cache, X-Varnish\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 612, in urlgrab
    return default_grabber.urlgrab(url, filename, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 976, in urlgrab
    return self._retry(opts, retryfunc, url, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 880, in _retry
    r = apply(func, (opts,) + args, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 962, in retryfunc
    fo = PyCurlFileObject(url, filename, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1056, in __init__
    self._do_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1308, in _do_open
    self._do_grab()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1438, in _do_grab
    self._do_perform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 1244, in _do_perform
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: https://github.com/henrysher/urlgrabber/blob/master/urlgrabber/grabber.py#L1527 <-- See the comment there

Comment: If you just want to download a jpg `urllib.urlretrieve('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/Passion_Flower.JPG/220px-Passion_Flower.JPG', filename='/home/my.jpg')` will do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use requests? I think it's simpler and achieves what you want. You may install it using:

```
pip install requests
```

and the code is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e0/Passion_Flower.JPG/220px-Passion_Flower.JPG')
>>> if r.status_code == 200:
>>>     open('/tmp/flower.jpg', 'w').write(r.content)
```

Comment: The question was "*why does it fail*?" Your answer would be on point if the question were "*how do I fix it*?" or "*what should I try instead*?" As it stands, your post would make an excellent comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thank you, Rob. Got it. I am new here. Really appreciate your comment.